# Silverlight MainPage object

Tags: silverlight

I am playing around with testing Silverlight application. One of the tutorials on the web uses MainPage object, where MainPage is the main Silverlight class. Eg:
  MainPage mp = new MainPage();
It's all good, but MainPage XAML has some controls that I can access at MainPage class code, eg, I can use
  txtPhotoUrl.Text;
to access
  
The problem is after creating an object of class MainPage I cannot access the XAML controls - I cannot see them in the list of MainPage object properties. Is this by design or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default MainPage controls has **internal** access modifier.So, you can access MainPage controls **from the same assembly**. For instance,

```
MainPage mp = new MainPage();
string text = mp.txtPhotoUrl.Text;
```

You can change access modifier using x:FieldModifier="[private/internal/public]" attribute in XAML for some control. For instance,

```
<!-- Accessible only from Code Behind-->
<TextBlock x:Name="txtPhotoUrl" x:FieldModifier="private" />

<!-- Accessible from other assemblies-->
<TextBlock x:Name="txtPhotoUrl" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

Comment: "Pro Bussiness Applications with Silverlight 4":http://books.google.ru/books?id=88pqq2H7kVwC&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=silverlight+x:FieldModifier&source=bl&ots=pldMTYGz4V&sig=EhWF-c-Xn9RHaVULcEyvp_3B0cM&hl=ru&ei=6PJUTpmGH8j34QSBsemqBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CGgQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=silverlight%20x%3AFieldModifier&f=false

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Yes, after I added x:FieldModifier="public" in XAML, this line in my C# code:
mp.txtPhotoUrl.Text;
doesnt throw any exception

Answer (score 1):

The identifier `txtPhotoUrl` refers to a `field` that has `internal` accessiblity.  Hence to access it your code would need to be in the same project.  You could use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute in the target probject so that the external code can access members marked as internal but your external code needs to be strongly named.